# Menu bar attached to window. Qt 6 / macOS

Tags: macos, qt, qml, menubar

I have updated the qt version of Mac program to 6.3 and menubar is now located **at the top edge of the window**, not native top macOS bar. How to move the menu to **the top of macOS screen next to the 'apple icon'**?
This is my code. It worked on qt 5.15.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 320
    height: 260
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Action { text: qsTr("&New...") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Open...") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Save") }
            Action { text: qsTr("Save &As...") }
            MenuSeparator { }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Quit") }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Edit")
            Action { text: qsTr("Cu&t") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Copy") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Paste") }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Help")
            Action { text: qsTr("&About") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe [these notes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/macos-issues.html#menu-bar) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special window flag for this. Try the following:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 320
    height: 260
    visible: true
    flags: ~Qt.AA_DontUseNativeMenuBar
    menuBar: MenuBar {...}
}
```

Comment: In Qt 6.3.1, this makes the title bar vanish, but the menu stays on the window!  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the Qt.labs.platform MenuBar instead of the default. As of Qt 6.3.1, the QML syntax is:

```
import Qt.labs.platform as Labs
...
ApplicationWindow {
    ...
    Labs.MenuBar  {
        Labs.Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Labs.MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&New")
                onTriggered: doNew()
            }
            Labs.MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: fileOpenDialog.open()
            }
            ...
        }
        Labs.Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Edit")
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The docs say this is only available on macOS, Android, and some flavors of Linux, but it's working properly on Windows, too.